# Get only property defined in protocol causes compilation error when modifying inner property of object

Tags: ios, swift

Consider code like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var something: Bool { get set }
}

class SomeProtocolImplementation: SomeProtocol {
    var something: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("something changed!")
        }
    }
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    var myProperty: SomeProtocol { get }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var myProperty: SomeProtocol = SomeProtocolImplementation() {
        didSet {
            print("myProperty has changed")
        }
    }
}


var o: MyProtocol = MyClass()
o.myProperty.something = true
```

This code doesn't compile with error:

```
error: cannot assign to property: 'myProperty' is a get-only property
o.myProperty.something = true
~~~~~~~~~~~~           ^
```

Why? My property is of type of SomeProtocolImplementation, which is class type so it should be possible to modify it's inner property using reference to myProperty.

Going further, after modifying myProperty definition so that it looks like that:

```
var myProperty: SomeProtocol { get set }
```

something weird happens. Now the code compile (not a surprise), but the output is:

```
something changed!
myProperty has changed
```

So at this point SomeProtocolImplementation starts behaving like a value type - modyifing it's internal state causes that the "didSet" callback for myProperty is triggered. Just as SomeProtocolImplementation would be struct...

I actually find the solution, but I want also understand what's going on. The solution is to modify SomeProtocol definition to:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    var something: Bool { get set }
}
```

It works fine, but I'm trying to understand why it behaves like this. Anybody able to explain?

Answer (score 1):

First read what [Class Only Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281) is. Concentrate on the note section that says:

> Use a class-only protocol when the behavior defined by that protocol’s requirements assumes or requires that a conforming type has **reference semantics** rather than value semantics.

Above quote should get you the idea.

You are trying to get the behavior of **reference type** for your `SomeProtocol`'s conforming class (i.e. `SomeProtocolImplementation`). You want to be able to change the value of `something` in future. So basically you are directing to the ***above quoted*** sentence.

If you need more clarification please consider the following more meaningful design where I changed the naming for convenience:

```
protocol Base: class {
    var referenceTypeProperty: Bool { get set }
    // By now you are assuming: this property should be modifiable from any reference.
    // So, instantly make the protocol `Class-only`
}

class BaseImplementation: Base {
    var referenceTypeProperty: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("referenceTypeProperty did set")
        }
    }
}

protocol Child {
    var valueTypeProperty: Base { get }
    // This property shouldn't be modifiable from anywhere.
    // So, you don't need to declare the protocol as Class-only
}

class ChildImplementation: Child {
    var valueTypeProperty: Base = BaseImplementation() {
        didSet {
            print("valueTypeProperty did set")
        }
    }
}

let object: Child = ChildImplementation()
object.valueTypeProperty.referenceTypeProperty = true
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any class that can provide behavior useful to other classes may declare a programmatic interface for vending that behavior anonymously. Any other class may choose to adopt the protocol and implement one or more of its methods, thereby making use of the behavior. The class that declares a protocol is expected to call the methods in the protocol if they are implemented by the protocol adopter.

[Protocol Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html)

When you try to 'set' value to a variable that is read-only - you are trying to change the protocol's implementation. Conforming classes can only consume information from protocol. In Swift we can write protocol extensions where we can have alternative methods for the protocol.

> In short think of computed variables as functions. You are technically trying to change a function in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> I actually find the solution, but I want also understand what's going on.

I was just about to tell you to make SomeProtocol a class protocol, but you already figured that out. — So I'm a little confused as to what you *don't* understand.

You understand about reference types and value types, and you understand about class protocols and nonclass protocols.

Well, as long as SomeProtocol might be adopted by a struct (it's a nonclass protocol), then if you are typing something *as* a SomeProtocol, it *is* a value type. The runtime isn't going to switch on reference type behavior just because the adopter turns out to be a class instance; all the decisions must be made at compile time. And at compile time, all the compiler knows is that this thing is a SomeProtocol, whose adopter might be a struct.